# How to include javascript in middleman 4?

Tags: javascript, sprockets, middleman, middleman-4

I've been using Middleman for a while and it always used the Rails asset pipeline for including javascript and css. So to include a javascript module called "thing.js" in the same directory, you'd do:

```
//= require thing
```

But since Middleman 4, that seems to have changed and I can't find any documentation. The closest thing I can find is this page which shows me how to run an ember.js compilation: https://middlemanapp.com/advanced/external-pipeline/

So... if I want to load javascript files in Middleman now, do I have to roll my own build system? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easy answer was to include the [middleman-sprockets](https://rubygems.org/gems/middleman-sprockets) gem. That way things will work like they used to.

Add this to your gemfile

```
gem 'middleman-sprockets', '~> 4.0.0.rc.1'
```

Run bundle install.

You don't need to activate anything, the middleman-sprockets extension auto-activates

Comment: Is sprockets working also for CSS? I have been fighting with this too without success!

Comment: If you can paste an example of how you used in the code it would be great. I can't figure this out and the help page for the gem isn't helpful. Also, trying to activate the gem, I got a double reference error message.

Comment: @AndreaMoro You need to include the development version of middleman-sprockets. Put this in your Gemfile: `gem 'middleman-sprockets', '~> 4.0.0.rc.1'` and run `bundle install`. You don't need to activate anything, the middleman-sprockets extension auto-activates.

Comment: Thanks, I did it ... but I figured out only after a while all my files need to be renamed as .scss otherwise they are not pipelined.

Comment: This does now require `activate :sprockets` in your `config.rb`